# Is there a way to "read" a gif/jpeg in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I need to read text from gif/jpeg that have a combination of text and images. The hope is that all the gifs are in a standard format for me to use regex (maybe?) to get text out of an image.

Any input on this is really appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean that you have an image of text, like a photo of text on a wall, or a screenshot? Or do you mean that the image file contains text characters embedded in the file?

Comment: I am not sure what your question is. To give you an example, consider a barcode image. I would like to extract the numbers below the barcode.

Comment: So you're not wanting to read text contained in the image file, but to read text contained in the picture itself? See @Andersol Imes answer - you're looking for OCR, and regexes will do absolutely nothing for you.

Comment: @Ken - Can you explain the difference between "text in an image file" and "text in a picture"? For a noob like me, both sound same

Comment: @unknown (yahoo): he's probably referring to metadata on the file or somesuch, rather than text embedded in the image.  There's a lot of text on the metadata of a jpeg for example when you take a photo with a camera about the camera, lighting, aperature, etc.

Answer (score 7):

This is called Optical Character Recognition (OCR).  There are a few libraries referenced in this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744966/any-open-source-c-ocr-library

Comment: The other OP has not mentioned which C# library worked for him/her. Can I assume that we need to write a wrapper for the only in the Google code library. Are there other free ones out there?

Comment: There's a LOT of help about getting the wrapper working in that post and links to other posts.  It will take you 30 minutes, max, trust me.  Here's the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744966/any-open-source-c-ocr-library/744978#744978

Comment: My understanding is that there are a lot of really crappy ones out there and a LOT of others that are extremely expensive.  This one happens to be awesome and free.  It'll be worth the 30 minutes learning how to use DLLImport, trust me.

Comment: The SO question linked to in the answer has been removed for some reason. Ugh. Does this mean we'll need to start posting the complete text from SO answers in SO answers, just in case the referenced answer gets removed?